# Super bad audio quality from iPhone 6s Plus speaker

Tags: audio, ios

When I use Skype on speaker on my iPhone 6s Plus with iOS 9.0.1, the sound from the speaker is horrible. I uploaded a [sample to SoundCloud](https://soundcloud.com/lihan-li-294216316/iphone6splus-ios9-broken-skype-voice-on-speaker).

I tested this on my iPad 4, and on the same OS, no such problem exists.

I had this phone for one day, and seems like this is a hardware problem. What do you think? I had this phone for barely a weekend, so if this is a hardware problem, I will be likely to have a chance to swap with a new phone!

Comment: Reboot the phone. Try turning on and off the handsfree (speaker) mode.

Comment: @mspasov I have done that, the issue persists.

Comment: Does it persist when you use other apps?

Comment: It looks like a software problem, not a hardware problem. Bad audio encoding maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Apple generally give 72 hours for a Dead On Arrival (DOA) or Early Life Failure (ELF) swaps.

I would take it to an Apple retail store as soon as possible to have them test it.

Answer (score 2):

I saw the same problem with my iPhone 6s Plus. I think it may be an issue with the Skype app since my FaceTime works without any issue.

Comment: ok, sounds like a software problem